# Writing to hard disk from contiguous physical memory

Tags: fwrite, mmap, hard-drive, dma, vfs

I have an ARM based device, running linux, which is connected to a camera, and I'm trying to store captured frames to HD efficiently.

- I'm developing in user space, but can modify drivers at will
- I'm coding in C
- Frames which are written into memory using DMA, and I have their physical memory pointer.
- I am able to control all the frame capturing flow, and I can tell when the frame buffers are stable (dqueued from the video4linux driver)
- Linux version is 3.0.35
- I'm familiar with kernel source code, not an expert, but I'm able to find my way in it and figure out things, as long as I get some hints...

I believe I have 2 alternatives:

1. Find the optimal configuration for my filesystem, for opening the file and writing into it. I'm now using ext4, and standard fopen() fwrite() functions. I understand I can also use mmap, or add O_DIRECT flag when calling open(), but didn't try it yet.
2. Find a way to pass the physical address of the buffer (I can get it
   from my Video4Linux driver) directly to the filesystem/hard drive driver,
   so the data will be transfered directly from there.

I found method 1 to be slow, having memory transactions as my bottleneck, since fwrite involves copying data from userspace to kernel space, and then again into some sort of cache, and then on to DMA. Too many memory transactions for a simple store...

Regarding method 2 - I don't know if that's possible, but if I was the one designing this system from scratch, this is what I would do.

Any thoughts?

- Regarding method 1 (using open() and write(), mmap() and/or O_DIRECT)
  can you recommend an optimal settings for my purpose?
- Is method 2 (storing to HD directly from an existing DMA buffer) possible? If so - can you point me to an example?

Comment: Please, can you be so kind to post the code snippet of the process? I have exactly the same problem, I understood that mmap is the solution, but can't understand how to use it.
Many thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

the only problem with writing into a file via mmap on UNIXs, is that you either have to deal with signals in case of out-of-disk-space 
or you have make certain that the file is not sparse
and thus all needed disk space is already allocated.
I think an uptodate G++ provides a method of converting signals into C++ exception handling,
but I'm not certain how supported this is on other systems than mac-os.